# CSS columns not updating on orientation change

Tags: css, ipad

I'm building a mobile webapp using CSS columns:

- When viewed on a phone, I want the content section to be single column.
- When it's on a tablet in portrait, I want the content area to have two columns.
- And when it's in landscape, I want it to have three.

It works perfectly on load or refresh, but the column count doesn't change on orientation change.

Here's the relevant **CSS**:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
    main {
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    main {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
    main {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    }
}
```

And here's a link to the page: http://bushidodesigns.net/bd

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out: if you apply the column count to an html tag, it doesn't update on orientation change. You need to have a class. In other words, this works:

```
@media (min-width: 960px) {
.my-div {
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-count: 3;
column-count: 3;
}
}
```

This does not:

```
@media (min-width: 960px) {
div {
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-count: 3;
column-count: 3;
}
}
```